# QWidgetWindow as QObject in event filter with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, eventfilter

In the migration from Qt4 to Qt5 for some code I have to filter events on my application but it does not work anymore. My software has to filter all events when in "Edition Mode" so only a few widgets/buttons can be available/clickable.

I have a class `InputGrabber` with a `QVector` of Pointers to `QWidget` and an `eventFilter` function. When passing to "Edit" mode , I append the widgets' pointers to the `QVector` of my `InputGrabber` that will be available:

```
_inputGrabber->add (_gpView);
_inputGrabber->add (_gpView->viewport ());
_inputGrabber->add (_gpView->horizontalScrollBar ());
_inputGrabber->add (_gpView->verticalScrollBar ());
_inputGrabber->add (_view->mainWindow().toolBarMap()["editSquel"]);
```

and then, on the eventFilter function the code goes like:

```
bool InputGrabber::eventFilter (QObject* object, QEvent* anevent)
{
    if (QInputEvent* event = dynamic_cast <QInputEvent*> (anevent))
      {
        QWidget* widget = dynamic_cast <QWidget*> (object);
        if (widget)
        {
          if (_widgetList.contains (widget) || _widgetList.contains (widget->parentWidget ()))
            return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);
          else if (QDialog* dlg = dynamic_cast <QDialog*> (widget))
            return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);
          else if (QDialogButtonBox* dlg = dynamic_cast <QDialogButtonBox*> (widget->parentWidget ()))
            return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);
          else
            return true;
        }
        else
          return true;
      }
      else
        return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);
    } 
}
```

The issue migrating to Qt5 is that the following cast:

```
QWidget* widget = dynamic_cast <QWidget*> (object);
```

returns `NULL` when object inherits from `QWidgetWindow`.

Has anyone found same issue and got a solution that follows the same strategy? I wouldn't like to change the behavior of my software, making loops on all widgets and setting `setDisabled()` for each one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there real reason to use `dynamic_cast`? Try `qobject_cast` insted. It has same syntax and works faster.

Comment: What's a `QWidgetWindow`?  Do you mean `QWindow`?  If so, why can't you simply repeat the `QWidget` logic for `QWindow` derived classes?

Comment: `QWidgetWindow` inherits from `QWindow` and not from `QWidget` in Qt5, so both dynamic_cast and qobject_cast will return `NULL`.

Comment: So [check for a window type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#isWindowType), and don't filter the event for such widgets?

Comment: @G.M. : QWidgetWindow is a class used in the implementation of Qt. As detailed in it's herader file : " This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to version without notice, or even be removed. ". So I guess it's a bad idea to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is wrong here:

```
return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);
```

should be

```
return QObject::eventFilter (object, anevent);
```

and possibly:

```
bool InputGrabber::eventFilter (QObject* object, QEvent* anevent)
{
  if (QInputEvent* event = dynamic_cast <QInputEvent*> (anevent))
  {
    //etc
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter (object, anevent);
}
```

this way, if you don't explicitly return true or false, it will always propagate the event in the chain correctly.

If your casts fail, just don't return anything and let it fall back to the last line. If somehow you stop the event propagation when you meet an object you don't know anything about (like the *misterious* QWidgetWindow) you are probably breaking the UI logic. If you let the propagation go on, it is very likely that the event you're waiting for will come out, soon or later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments and replies. In the future, I'll be using the qobject_cast for QObjects, but the solution came following the logic suggested by @p-a-o-l-o : if the widget cast fails, then I let the event propage freely:
if ( widget)
{//some code here
}
else
       return QObject::eventFilter (object, event);